# What do square brackets above the bottom staff mean?

Tags: piano, notation

[image: Leonard Ornstein's Tarantelle M.1]
*From Leonard Ornstein's Tarantelle (1963)*
Unlike pedal markings, these are above the bottom staff. I feel like it could be phrasing, but that's normally indicated by the beaming of the notes. What do these groupings mean?

Comment: @AndrewLi That would make sense if this was 9/8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* phrasing.  It's a kind of regrouping of the beats in the left hand, from 4 beats in the bar to 3.  It's much more visual using the brackets than just using phrase marks.

Comment: Wouldn't this normally be notated using note beaming? I think that would be equally as visual.

Comment: @Okoyos  note beaming is usually broken at the start of each beat. I have seen beaming,e.g., of groups of 6 16th notes in 4/4 time, but that's a bit easier to interpret than beaming eighth notes in  6/8 or 12/8 time.

Comment: @Okoyos it occurs to me also that, since this is a piano piece, beaming the LH part but not the RH part would make it visually tough to identify synchronized notes.

Comment: @Okoyos Yeah, if this were written by Bartók I think it would definitely be shown with a beaming pattern. But not everyone likes that notation method because it can be hard to read. It looks to me that this composer is trying to find a compromise that preserves the readability of proper 12/8 beam patterns but still shows the anti-metric grouping. It also might be someone dealing with a notation program that can’t do the other beaming easily—note the strangely uncentered 12/8, this doesn’t look like a high quality program.

Comment: @PatMuchmore Also included in Tarantelle are some double beaming in the left hand. I would think that also signifies phrasing, so it seems odd that they would have two different ways of expressing phrasing. Why do you think that is?